# Size of array with two pointers

Tags: c

I have a function receiving two pointers, the first member of the array and behind the last one, i can not use for loop, do and do while. How to get the pointer to the middle member of the array ? i'm the beginner.

Comment: pointer arithmetic is your friend

Comment: you need to know array type

Answer (score 2):

use pointer arithmetic to compute the distance between pointers in number of elements, and divide by 2. Then add to the `start`.

```
void foo(const int *start, const int *end)
{
     assert(start != end); // avoid returning invalid pointer if list is empty
     const int *middle = start + (end - start)/2;
     ...
}
```

There are probably one-off errors & adjustments to make depending on the algorithm you want (ex: left or right bisect, if the list contains only 1 element, you may want to choose middle as the first element (code above does that), but you may want to add 1 to choose beyond element) but that's the general idea, no loops, `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: If the list has one element, `start` is not equal to `last`. `last-start` would be one. The problem states they are given a pointer to “behind” the last element.

Comment: right, behind, so it's the end. but the formula doesn't change. Dividing 1 by 2 yields 0 too.